# Trouble with struct malloc in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm currently getting started with C, and can't come up with a solution for this.

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
   char *name;
   int ID;
   [...]
} example;  

int currentID = 1;

int new_example(char *name){

   char *the_name = malloc(strlen(name) * sizeof(char));
   example *test = malloc(sizeof(example));

   test->name = name;
   test->ID = currentID;
   currentID++;

   [...]

   return test->ID;
}
```

Now I know that I have to use malloc (and free) for the "name" member of that struct, as well as for the struct itself. What I'm doing right now is just allocating memory to the_name, but the test->name has no memory allocated for it. So I guess my question is, how do I write test->name into the previously malloc'd memory? Sorry if my question isn't clear enough, I don't really know how to explain it better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should not compile. `example` is a variable, not a type -- you may want to write `struct example {...};`. And whenever you want to use the type (in C, not in C++) you must write `struct example`, like in `struct example *test;`.

Comment: It does compile fine though

Comment: Doesn't with gcc: `error: ‘test’ undeclared (first use in this function)`. I guess it tries to multiply `example`  with `test`.

Comment: For the compilation error Cf. http://ideone.com/PB50Ng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
  example *test = malloc(sizeof(example));

  test->name = malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char)); // +1 for null terminator
  test->ID = currentID;

  strcpy(test->name, name);//copy name contents
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! If you don't mind, I have a followup question. I have a function to free the memory again, free_example(example *test). How would I go about correctly freeing the struct? free(test->name); free(test); gives me a segmentation fault. Am I doing it wrong or do I have a mistake elsewhere?

Comment: `free(test->name);`, `free(test);` is correct. There is probably a mistake elsewhere

Comment: The `+1` should be applied to `strlen(name)`, not the result of the multiplication

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is there a multiplication? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Point the pointer to the new memory

```
char *the_name = malloc((strlen(name)+1) * sizeof(char));
example *test = malloc(sizeof(example));

test->name = the_name ;
```

And copy the string to it

```
strcpy( test->name , name )  ;
```

Notice that you need to allocate one more character for the null terminator:

`strlen(name)+1) * sizeof(char)`

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like the following:

```
int new_example(char *name){

   example *test = malloc( sizeof *test ); // or calloc( 1, sizeof *test )
   if ( test ) // you should always check the result of malloc or calloc
   {   
     test->name = calloc( strlen( name ) + 1,   // + 1 for 0 terminator
                          sizeof *test->name );  
     if ( test->name )
     {
       strcpy( test->name, name );
       test->ID = currentID;
       currentID++;

       [...]
       return test->ID;
     }
     else
       free( test );
   }
   return -1; // error indication
}
```

Some notes:

- I prefer using `sizeof *test` over `sizeof ( example )`; if I ever change the type of `test`, I don't have to worry about changing the corresponding type in the `malloc` or `calloc` call.  Same for `sizeof *test->name`.  By definition, `sizeof ( char )` == 1, so that `calloc` call can be
  written `calloc( strlen( name ) + 1, 1 )`, but I still like the explicit `sizeof` expression in case you decide to use `wchar` for name (or some other wide character type).
- `calloc` zeros out the memory it allocates.  For most types this doesn't matter, but I makes sense when allocating space for strings.
- You should *always* check the result of `malloc` and `calloc` calls.  If you can't allocate memory for `test`, then you shouldn't try to allocate memory for `test->name`.  Similarly, if you can't allocate memory for `test->name`, that's probably an indication of something bad, so you should back out what you've done so far.
- I am assuming that you are storing `test` to some persistent structure in the `[...]` section; if not, you have a memory leak, because you lose the `test` pointer when the function exits.

When you free the object, you'll want to free the `name` member first, like the following:

```
void delete_example( example *ex )
{
  free( ex->name );
  free( ex );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 

All my "example"s are saved in an array. There's a Examples[ID] = *this; somewhere in the [...], is that fine? (According to my logic) It should always give me the structure I want when I use Examples[_ID of the structure I want_], right?

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to allocate the memory as a separate step (but if you must, remember to add another byte for the terminating `'\0'`). Use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) to assign `test->name` directly, with its own new copy of `name`:

```
int new_example(char *name){
  example *test = malloc(sizeof(example));

  test->name = strdup(name);
  test->ID = currentID;
  currentID++;

  [...]

  return test->ID;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

do

```
   test->name = strdup(name);
```

strdup will measure the string, malloc some memory, copy the string and return the malloced memory to you

Comment: Not all implementations support `strdup`.